# Django error: Relation does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql, django-allauth, django-1.6

I have this user profiles model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    age = models.IntegerField(null = True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True, default ="")
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True, default ="")
    updated_profile = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{}'s profile".format(self.user.username)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_profile'

    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

    post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

When I try a `UserProfile.objects.all()` through shell or code I get this:

```
ProgrammingError: relation "user_profile" does not exist
LINE 1: ...play_name", "user_profile"."updated_profile" FROM "user_prof...
```

I have tried schemamigration, migrate, syncdb, have deleted and recreated whole DB i in postgres. Still same error.

Edit: I also have django-allauth installed. I suppose that could interfere with this model.

Comment: Which line return the error. Because your relation with User seems good. Can you give us others models please ?

Comment: So far this is the only model I have. Here's full traceback: http://pastebin.com/F5ux2kz5. Also I just edited the post to include full model. Had removed a few fields to make it more readable.

Comment: have you tried syncdb without specifying db_table ?

Comment: yeah, then I get this error: `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "userprofiles_userprofile" already exists`

Comment: Are your `create_user_profile` and `post_save` placed inside model? I have suspicion that it may causes problem, try to place it outside of model

Comment: @jedema I just realized that I have django-allauth installed. I guess that could interfere with my model.

Comment: @coldmind correct, they should be outside of the model class.

Comment: Think I finally got to the bottom of this. I seems like the table already existed in the database and running `./manage.py migrate userprofiles --fake` seemed to have gotten past that. Thanks anyways!